# How to compare Resolution dates between parent and child in JQL or ScriptRunner

Tags: jira, jql, scriptrunner-for-jira

Am trying to do a comparison between parent issues and subtasks to find subtasks that have been resolved after the parent issue was completed.

Need to compare the resolution date between parent and child issues to find out when the child issue has a greater date value.

I have Adaptavist Scriptrunner and have used both the date compare and the subtasks function but am struggling.  Would appreciate any help, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can' do this via jql itself.
But you can write script to get this data.
Something like

```
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.search.SearchService
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager

import java.sql.Timestamp

Class_Answer script = new Class_Answer()
script.getAnswer()

class Class_Answer {

SearchService searchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchService.class)
UserManager userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
ApplicationUser sysUser = userManager.getUserByName("some_user") //user with permission to browse your project
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

void getAnswer() {

    String query = "project = TEST AND issueFunction in hasSubtasks()"
    List<MutableIssue> issues = getIssuesByJql(query)
    issues.each { parentIssue ->
        Timestamp parentResolvedDate = parentIssue.getResolutionDate()
        if (parentResolvedDate) {
            Collection<Issue> subtaskList = parentIssue.getSubTaskObjects()
            subtaskList.each { subtaskIssue ->
                Timestamp subtaskResolvedDate = subtaskIssue.getResolutionDate()
                if (subtaskResolvedDate) {
                    if (subtaskResolvedDate.after(parentResolvedDate)) {
                        log.warn("parent: ${parentIssue}: ${parentResolvedDate} : subtask: ${subtaskIssue} : ${subtaskIssue.resolutionDate}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


List<MutableIssue> getIssuesByJql(String JqlQuery) {
    List<MutableIssue> IssuesByJql = new ArrayList<MutableIssue>()
    SearchService.ParseResult parseResult = searchService.parseQuery(sysUser, JqlQuery)
    if (parseResult.isValid()) {
        def searchResult = searchService.search(sysUser, parseResult.getQuery(), PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
        IssuesByJql = searchResult.results.collect { issueManager.getIssueObject(it.id) }
    } else {
        log.warn("Search query not valid: " + JqlQuery)
    }
    return IssuesByJql
}
}
```

Too much if's and some bad logic but you get the idea.
Or you can write your own jql function as described here
https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.9/jira/custom-jql-functions.html
add it to your jira, then use it for search in issue navigator